# How to remove apostrophe marks from a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I'd like to remove all the '' from each symbol using Python.

'MMM’, ‘AXP’, ‘AAPL’, ‘BA’, ‘CAT’, ‘CVX’, ‘CSCO’, ‘KO’, ‘DD’, ‘XOM’, ‘GE’, ‘GS’, ‘HD’, ‘IBM’, ‘INTC’, ‘JNJ’, ‘JPM’, ‘MCD’, ‘MRK’, ‘MSFT’, ‘NKE’, ‘PFE’, ‘PG’, ‘TRV’, ‘UNH’, ‘UTX’, ‘VZ’, ‘V’, ‘WMT’, ‘DIS’

so I end up with: MMM, AXP, AAPL, BA, and so on...

I tried

```
str = 
'MMM’, ‘AXP’, ‘AAPL’, ‘BA’, ‘CAT’, ‘CVX’, ‘CSCO’, ‘KO’, ‘DD’, ‘XOM’, ‘GE’, ‘GS’, ‘HD’, ‘IBM’, ‘INTC’, ‘JNJ’, ‘JPM’, ‘MCD’, ‘MRK’, ‘MSFT’, ‘NKE’, ‘PFE’, ‘PG’, ‘TRV’, ‘UNH’, ‘UTX’, ‘VZ’, ‘V’, ‘WMT’, ‘DIS’
```

and then:

```
str2 = str.replace("''","")
```

but to no avail. any ideas?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to name your variables like Python types (`str` is a type). Also your sample (the `str = ` part) produces a `SyntaxError` when copied. Could you provide a working [mcve]?

Comment: That assignment is not legal syntax.  Please provide a valid example.

Comment: Maybe it _is_ legal syntax, but a newline snuck in when formatting the question.  If so, it means that str is now a tuple.  +1 to request a working, minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: someone was a bit heavy handed with the vote down -. I guess it's satisfying on some level to them. I was just looking for an answer. thanks for the input.

Comment: Prune - MarianD understood it perfectly. Check out the accepted answer below. No need to be deliberately obtuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.replace("‘", '').replace("’", '').replace("'", '')
```

(in double quotes ara all possible aphostrophes).

Comment: Note if you're saving this in code you should specify the encoding of the file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top under the `#!/usr/bin/env python` line if present. Also if you're using python 2.x you should specify it is a unicode string `u"‘"`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to replace `''` which is not present in your string, just replace `'`.

```
In [8]: a = "'a'"

In [9]: a
Out[9]: "'a'"

In [10]: a.replace("'", "") # This works
Out[10]: 'a'

In [11]: a.replace("''", "") # Your attempt
Out[11]: "'a'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking it to replace double-apostrophes with the code `str.replace("''","")`, but the apostrophes in your string are all individual. You should try just with a single like `str.replace("'","")`

Also you might be running into a problem where they are not apostrophes, but single quotation marks, in which case you might need something like:

```
str = str.replace("'", "")`
str = str.replace(u"\u2018", "")` # LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2018)
str = str.replace(u"\u2019", "")` # RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019)
```

Comment: In my case, compile time Error is  "cannot resolve symbol u".

Comment: And how to check if a String contains \u2018 ? What to write in str.contains() ?

Comment: @AnishMittal Can you post a new question with the details?